# Relations, Equivalence Relations, Partitions

Tags: equivalence-relations

Consider A=$\mathbb{Z}$. For each integer $n$, define

$$B_n = \{{m\in \mathbb{Z}\ | \ (\exists q)(m=n+5q)}\}.$$

Prove that $\{{B_n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$. Identify the equivalence classes.

Comment: Are $B_n$ and $B_{n-5}$ disjoint . Because $m = n + 5q = n-5 + 5(q+1)$. So they are not disjoint. Unless in the definition something is missing.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @ChirantanChowdhury Those sets are identical, which is not a problem. (If they weren't identical they would have to be disjoint and your objection would be relevant.)

Comment: So we need to consider only $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5$ which are disjoint by  the division algorithm applied to a number divided by 5.

Comment: This is **NOT** a do-my-homework-for-me site. Within an hour you've posted two questions that are just copy-and-pasted texts of probably homework questions, without adding anything from yourself at all. If you're unwilling to make any effort on your homework, why should other people do that for you?

Comment: I saw those questions from the book. I'm trying to answer them but I'm stuck with these questions. I tried answering them but with all my effort, I really can't. it's frustrating :(

Comment: What is your have you done to solve the problem? You need to show your effort.

Answer (score 1):

$B_n$ is the set of all the numbers that is congruent to $n$ modulo $5$. Now obviously

1. Reflexive: $a\equiv a~(mod~5)$,
2. Transitive: $a\equiv b~(mod~5)$ and $b\equiv c~(mod~5)$ implies $a\equiv c~(mod~5)$,
3. Symmetric: $a\equiv b~(mod~5)$ implies $b\equiv a~(mod~5)$

Comment: These are correct statements. They don't directly answer the OP's questions.